# How to set up a PayPal monthly payment with varying amounts

Tags: flutter, paypal, subscription, billing, recurring-billing

I'm currently building a Flutter application with an unusual subscription model. The idea is that depending on how the user uses the app, they would seamlessly be charged a different amount of money each month. I plan to use PayPal, and I've looked into their REST API, this is what I found: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/#definition-agreement_details

In this API endpoint, I'm assuming I can setup a Billing Agreement for each user of a specific amount_range, where once the user agrees to the payment, I'd be allowed to seamlessly charge each user a varying amount, within that range.

Am I correct in my conclusion?
Would this be the best approach?
if not, can you point me in the right direction for how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

I do not want to use the deprecated API. it's very important to be using REST API.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Billing Agreement API you link to is deprecated.

Using the current [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/subscriptions/), if you create a unique Plan for each subscriber, you can [update that Plan](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/subscriptions/add-capabilities/update-plan-pricing/) > 10 days before their next billing date, and they will receive an email notification of the new amount.

You can use [webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions) to keep track of active subscriptions and the last time you've been successfully paid for one.

If you need an internal ID for reconciliation, set the parameter `custom_id` when you first create the subscription; its value will be returned in webhook events for that subscription.

Comment: Thanks for the help! One question tho: Does this require user action for every time I update the agreement?